# Repalce SceneKit view background with a custom CIImage

Tags: scenekit, arkit, metalkit

I modify the ARFrame `CVPixelBuffer` with `VNGeneratePersonSegmentationRequest`, in the end it gives me a `CIImage` that contains all my modification.
My goal is to remove or replace the SceneKit view background with my CIImage in realtime.

for example I can add metalView and draw the CIImage on it, like it:

```
            // grab command buffer so we can encode instructions to GPU
        guard let commandBuffer = metalCommandQueue.makeCommandBuffer() else {
            return
        }

        // grab image
        guard let ciImage = currentCIImage else {
            return
        }

        // ensure drawable is free and not tied in the preivous drawing cycle
        guard let currentDrawable = view.currentDrawable else {
            return
        }
        
        // make sure the image is full screen
        let drawSize = cameraView.drawableSize
        let scaleX = drawSize.width / ciImage.extent.width
        let scaleY = drawSize.height / ciImage.extent.height
        
        let newImage = ciImage.transformed(by: .init(scaleX: scaleX, y: scaleY))
        //render into the metal texture
        self.ciContext.render(newImage,
                              to: currentDrawable.texture,
                              commandBuffer: commandBuffer,
                              bounds: newImage.extent,
                              colorSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB())

        // register drawwable to command buffer
        commandBuffer.present(currentDrawable)
        commandBuffer.commit()
```

But still I don't now how I can my metal View which called `cameraView` to add it in the background of `ARSCNView`, I mean by background is, the background only should changes, and I still can add object and interact with object above that background.

here is my ARSCNView model

```
class VirtualObjectARView: ARSCNView {

    // MARK: Position Testing
    
    /// Hit tests against the `sceneView` to find an object at the provided point.
    func virtualObject(at point: CGPoint) -> VirtualObject? {
        let hitTestOptions: [SCNHitTestOption: Any] = [.boundingBoxOnly: true]
        let hitTestResults = hitTest(point, options: hitTestOptions)
        
        return hitTestResults.lazy.compactMap { result in
            return VirtualObject.existingObjectContainingNode(result.node)
        }.first
    }
    
    // - MARK: Object anchors
    
    func addOrUpdateAnchor(for object: VirtualObject) {
        // If the anchor is not nil, remove it from the session.
        if let anchor = object.anchor {
            session.remove(anchor: anchor)
        }
        
        // Create a new anchor with the object's current transform and add it to the session
        let newAnchor = ARAnchor(transform: object.simdWorldTransform)
        object.anchor = newAnchor
        session.add(anchor: newAnchor)
    }
}

extension ARSCNView {
   
    ///  Type conversion wrapper for original `unprojectPoint(_:)` method. Used in contexts where sticking to SIMD3<Float> type is helpful.
    func unprojectPoint(_ point: SIMD3<Float>) -> SIMD3<Float> {
        return SIMD3<Float>(unprojectPoint(SCNVector3(point)))
    }
    
    // - Tag: CastRayForFocusSquarePosition
    func castRay(for query: ARRaycastQuery) -> [ARRaycastResult] {
        return session.raycast(query)
    }

    // - Tag: GetRaycastQuery
    func getRaycastQuery(for alignment: ARRaycastQuery.TargetAlignment = .any) -> ARRaycastQuery? {
        return raycastQuery(from: screenCenter, allowing: .estimatedPlane, alignment: alignment)
    }
    
    var screenCenter: CGPoint {
        return CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY)
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help in advance